# Vim: record macro entering insert mode via mapping

Tags: vim, macros

I'm trying to have remap i/c/o/a and friends to always record a macro. But the keypress that actually brings me into insert mode is not recorded (explained below).

For example, if we have:

```
nnoremap i qzi
inoremap <esc> <esc>q
```

Ideally, this means that when I enter insert mode (`i`), I also start recording to register `z`. And when I leave (`<esc>`), we stop recording. So register z should have the entire sequence needed to repeat what I did in insert mode.

But then if I try to type in insert mode (e.g., `ihelloworld<esc>`) and then check `:registers a`, I get

```
---Registers---
"z   helloworld^[
```

**Notice how the `i` command is not included -- only what i typed in insert mode is.**

Why is this happening? What can I do to get around it?

I also noticed that if I just typed `qzihelloworld<esc>` normally, the `z` register DOES contain `ihelloworld<esc>` (with the `i`).

For those interested, I'm doing trying to do this because certain operations break 'repeat last command (the period key `.`)'. For example, if you use `<c-o>` or move around while insert-mode, `.` will only repeat the last segment of your insert mode. In particular, I'm trying to find a workaround for an autoclosing plugin

Comment: It doesn't answer your question, but a patch is available to solve your *problem* of not being able to [move the cursor without breaking undo](https://groups.google.com/forum/m/#!topic/vim_dev/gBumYDSEJoo).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As @Carpetsmoker explains why it doesn't get recorded:

From [`:help q`](http://vimhelp.appspot.com/repeat.txt.html#recording)

> The 'q' command is disabled while executing a register, and it doesn't work inside a mapping and :normal.

So that explains why it doesn't work ...

---

**A solution:**

As the command (e.g., `i`) in the mapping is not recorded, a solution is to prepend it to the recorded buffer when leaving insert mode.

To distinguish between `i`, `a`, `o`, etc, you can store the command in a variable, and then prepend *that* to the recorded macro:

```
nnoremap i :let b:mode="i"<cr>qzi
nnoremap a :let b:mode="a"<cr>qza
nnoremap o :let b:mode="o"<cr>qzo

inoremap <Esc> <Esc>q :let @z=":normal! ".b:mode.@z<CR>
```

Simply prepending `i` (etc.) to the macro doesn't work (for me) since it triggers the mapping for `i`. Calling it with `normal!` fixes that.

Another option is to modify the macro to enter insert using `startinsert` (combined with suitable movements to emulate `i`, `a`, `o`, etc.) by prepending the macro like this

```
:let @z=":startinsert^M".@z
```

**caveat:** Your rationale for wanting this:

> For example, if you use `<c-o>` or **move around** while insert-mode, `.` will only repeat the last segment of your insert mode.

(*my emphasis*) needs the warning that *"moving around"* (with arrow keys) does not work (at least in my quick tests) without additional hacking, as the arrow keys send an `<esc> ...` sequence, triggering the end of the recording mapping for `<esc>`. `c-o` will work though, so you *can* move around (slowly) with e.g. `<c-o> h` (for moving left).

**Another problem** is that replaying it as a macro does not work (with this solution at least, perhaps due to the use of `normal!`) if you have newlines, etc., in the recorded macro. A solution to that is to `execute` the buffer instead of replaying it as a macro. That is, `:exe @z` instead of `@z` for instance with the mapping

```
nnoremap <space>z :execute @z<cr>
```

Comment: You should add a space between `q:` and `let`.; there's a reason my answer has this. Enter `:startinsert` and `<Esc>` to see why :-) Also, there are more ways to enter insert mode; [this page should list them all](https://vi.stackexchange.com/tags/insert-mode/info)